# in bash moved backwards to some previous line, how to get hist line number?

Tags: bash, history

When I have bash history like

```
101 eoho 1
102 echo 2
103 echo 3
```

then

```
history 1
```

shows

```
103 echo 3
```

Now with hitting twice the up-arrow, I have after the prompt the comnand line

```
echo 1
```

without the history line number.
Thus if I type ***RETURN*** the comnand

```
echo 1
```

would be executed.

Yet before executing this displayed command, I would like to prove that this command is really from history line 101.

Is there a way to query for the history line number without to leave, to loose, to execute the found previous history line.

Like

```
history 1
```

doese

Perhaps out of another terminal, perhaps similar as using
writevt

Regards

Comment: If you know the number then there is no point in up-arrow-ing there, risking a mistake and thus needing to confirm that this is really the desired line. Just use `fc 101`.